# Import package in javascript file which is script for html

Tags: javascript, electron

I am doing electron project. In it every tutorial i have watched is adding js in `<script>` tag i want to separate the js code from html. So i

```
...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./../scripts/upload.js" ></script>
...
        <input onchange="upload()" id='train-button' type="file">File</input>
....
```

and in js file i

```
function upload(){
    const electron = require('electron');
    const {ipcRenderer} = electron;

    if (x.files.length == 0) {
        alert("Select one or more files.");
    }else{
        ipcRenderer.send("saveFile",targetFile,destinationPath)
    }
}
```

Now here i am getting error that

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

but if i define require outside the upload function then it is not running that line and saying

```
electron is undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `nodeIntegration:true` in your BrowserWindow config. Doing so will enable `require` in your js file.

**However**, this is *very poor* security practice. I recommend using a [security-focused template](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template).

[This post](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/blob/master/docs/newtoelectron.md) might also help explain to you more about best-practices in electron apps regarding using IPC between renderer/main processes.